# Can I run very heavy tasks in Firebase Cloud Functions and monitor the progress to my app?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-functions

For example, if I need to run a loop that takes an hour. Can I use Firebase Cloud Functions to do it?

If so, can I monitor the progress to my Android app when every 1% is done? How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Cloud Functions are meant for relatively short-term tasks, and cannot run longer than 9 minutes. So for larger workloads you'll either have to cut them into smaller pieces that complete within the maximum time, or run the workload on another type of compute infrastructure.